# How to make a dictionary from a text file with python

Tags: python, dictionary, distinct-values

My file looks like this:

```
aaien 12 13 39
aan 10
aanbad 12 13 14 57 58 38
aanbaden 12 13 14 57 58 38
aanbeden 12 13 14 57 58 38
aanbid  12 13 14 57 58 39
aanbidden 12 13 14 57 58 39
aanbidt 12 13 14 57 58 39
aanblik 27 28
aanbreken 39
...
```

I want to make a dictionary with key = the word (like 'aaien') and the value should be a list of the numbers that are next to it. 
So it has to look this way:
{'aaien': ['12, 13, 39'], 'aan': ['10']}

This code doesn't seem to work.

```
document = open('LIWC_words.txt', 'r')
liwcwords = document.read()
dictliwc = {}
for line in liwcwords:
    k, v = line.strip().split(' ')
    answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()

liwcwords.close()
```

python gives this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are splitting your line into a list of words, but only giving it one key and value.

This will work:

```
with open('LIWC_words.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:  # empty line?
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

Note that you don't need to give `.split()` an argument; without arguments it'll both split on whitespace *and strip the results for you*. That saves you having to explicitly call `.strip()`.

The alternative is to split only on the first whitespace:

```
with open('LIWC_words.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        if line.strip():  # non-empty line?
            key, value = line.split(None, 1)  # None means 'all whitespace', the default
            answer[key] = value.split()
```

The second argument to `.split()` limits the number of splits made, guaranteeing that there at most 2 elements are returned, making it possible to unpack the values in the assignment to `key` and `value`.

Either method results in:

```
{'aaien': ['12', '13', '39'],
 'aan': ['10'],
 'aanbad': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbaden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbeden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbid': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanbidden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanbidt': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanblik': ['27', '28'],
 'aanbreken': ['39']}
```

If you still see only *one* key and the rest of the file as the (split) value, your input file is using a non-standard line separator perhaps. Open the file with [universal line ending support](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines), by adding the `U` character to the mode:

```
with open('LIWC_words.txt', 'rU') as document:
```

Comment: your line is probably empty

Comment: @user2007220: Added tests to skip empty lines.

Comment: Just to note that `for line in liwcwords` could simply be `for line in document` - scrapping the `document.read()` part

Comment: @JonClements: The mapping name was also mismatched; corrected both.

Comment: Okay, this already very useful... But now we have this: {'aaien': ['12', '13', '39', 'aan', '10', 'aanbad', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbaden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbeden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbid', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', 'aanbidden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', 'aanbidt', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', ... ]} ... So this is a dictionary for 'aaien' and all the rest are values...

Comment: @user2007220: Look at how the file is read; I've changed that. Don't use `.read()` (that gives you one big file), use `for line in openfileobject` instead.

Comment: I'm very glad... but I still have an important problem (read earlier comment)

Comment: @user2007220: Using `.read()` you get the whole file as one string, including newlines. My solution instead treats the file like an iterator (loops over the file itself); that gives you the data one line at a time.

Comment: Somehow it still doesn't work... I used exactly your code and still it gives me 'aaien': ['12', '13', '39', 'aan', '10', 'aanbad', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbaden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbeden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38', 'aanbid', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', 'aanbidden', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', 'aanbidt', '12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39', ... ]}... I'm so sorry, i'm just a beginner in this...

Comment: @user2007220: What kind of newlines does your file contain? I suspect it is *not* a standard `\n` but something else. What does `print repr(open('LIWC_words.txt').read(30))` give you? You can try opening the file using universal line ending support instead; answer updated.

Comment: 'aaien 12 13 39\raan 10\raanbad 1'

Comment: @user2007220: Bingo; those `'\r'` characters are *carriage returns*; open the file using `'rU'` instead and it should work. `'\r'` is a old Macintosh convention.

Comment: @user2007220: Glad to have been of assistance. Alsjeblieft! :-)

Comment: @user2007220: Bare hygellig. Of, geen dank nodig, from an expat cheesehead with actual clogs by the door..

Answer (score 2):

```
>liwcwords = document.read()  
>dictliwc = {}    
>for line in liwcwords:
```

You are iterating over a string here, which is not what you want. Try `document.readlines()`. Here is a another solution.

```
from pprint import pprint
with open('LIWC_words.txt') as fd:
    d = {}
    for i in fd:
        entry = i.split()
        if entry: d.update({entry[0]: entry[1:]})

pprint(d)
```

Here is how the output looks like

```
{'aaien': ['12', '13', '39'],
 'aan': ['10'],
 'aanbad': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbaden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbeden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '38'],
 'aanbid': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanbidden': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanbidt': ['12', '13', '14', '57', '58', '39'],
 'aanblik': ['27', '28'],
 'aanbreken': ['39']}
```